# Selecting rows with in R

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I have following dataset,

```
   Type Model.rmsep Model.r2pred variable     value
1 train      Linear       Linear    RMSEP 0.1067979
2  test   PLS.Comp7    PLS.Comp7    RMSEP 0.1008264
3    cv  PCR.Comp17   PCR.Comp16    RMSEP 0.1227625
4 train      Linear       Linear   R2pred 0.9190042
5  test   PLS.Comp7    PLS.Comp7   R2pred 0.9143945
6    cv  PCR.Comp17   PCR.Comp16   R2pred 0.8916413
```

I want to select those rows from second column which has maximum `RMSEP` for each `Type` and those rows from third column which has maximum `R2pred` for each `Type`. I want to bind the result and get something like below:

```
   Type       Model variable     value
1 train      Linear    RMSEP 0.1067979
2  test   PLS.Comp7    RMSEP 0.1008264
3    cv  PCR.Comp17    RMSEP 0.1227625
4 train      Linear   R2pred 0.9190042
5  test   PLS.Comp7   R2pred 0.9143945
6    cv  PCR.Comp16   R2pred 0.8916413
```

It would be nice to use `plyr` package if possible.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want. It looks like you're just dropping a column? You certainly do not need plyr for that.

Comment: Did you try anything? Got stuck somewhere?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried in the question, with the result you obtained with it, so that we can tell you what is wrong with your code. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm assuming you have more data than what you posted, so you're doing more than dropping a column.  But you need to know how to get a dataset with maximums over subsets of your data.  See below.

Comment: I am not droping a column, there are some changes..

Comment: So is the answer I posted doing what you want?

Comment: But i want maximum from R2pred and minimum from RMSEP, so the variables should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

First, here's a play dataset:

```
play.data <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=1000, ncol=3))
names(play.data) <- c("Type", "variable", "value")
play.data$Type<- sample(x=c("train", "test", "cv"), size=1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .25, .25))
play.data$variable <- sample(x=c("RMSEP", "R2pred"), size=1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))
play.data$value <- runif(1000)
```

Now just use ddply, and then sort into your desired order.

```
## Now get the max 
max.data <- ddply (play.data,.(Type, variable), summarize, max_value=max(value))
max.data <- max.data[order(max.data$variable), ]
```